# Trying to get value from option on selected tag with jQuery and post to php page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post

I'm trying to get value from the selected option and post on a Php. But I also have a form to Post data as well. I'm trying to combine the two but now when I try to run the code I get a blank query page.

**message.php**

```
    <form  id="messageEmployeeForm" class="form table-striped" method="POST" action="core/query.php">

<select  id='toEmployee' class='form-control formBlock' name='toEmployee_id' value='' type='text' class='form-control formBlock'>
                     <option value="">To...</option>
                       <?php
        $employeesQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employees");
        while ($employee = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $employeesQuery)) {
            ?>
      <option id='toEmployees_id' name='toEmployees_id' value="<?php echo $employee['employee_id'] ;?>">

     <?php echo $employee['first_name'] ;?> <?php echo $employee['last_name'] ;?></option>
     <?php } ;?>
    </select> 


//other inputs here...

        <input name="sendMessage" id="submit" type="submit" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#toEmployee").bind("change", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { data: $("#toEmployee").val() }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**query.php**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['sendMessage']) && isset($_POST['data'])){
$var = $_POST['data'];
//other data to be posted and bind here using prepared statements...

]
```

Comment: Maybe try `$("#toEmployee option:selected").val()` this will take the select value of the `select`

Answer (score 0):

Your **query.php** file is expecting two post keys to be present during the request, without these it won't run the inner code.

```
isset($_POST['sendMessage']) && isset($_POST['data'])
```

Therefore inside your jQuery, you need to additionally send the `sendMessage` key like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        data: $("#toEmployee").val(),
        sendMessage: 'your value'
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // do something with output (data)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that. Make sense but still when I hit "submit" query.php returns blank. Code update :     `$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#toEmployee").bind("change", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 
                        data: $("#toEmployee").val(),
                        sendMessage: $("#submit").val()
                    
            };
                });
            });
        });`

Comment: You need to add a `success` function to your AJAX request, see updated answer.

Comment: UPDATE:   `$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#toEmployee").bind("change", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 
                        
                data: $("#toEmployee").val() ,
                    sendMessage : $("#submit").val()
                
            },
            
            success: function(data) {
                  if(data === true){
      jQuery('#successp').css("display","block")
      };

    }
        
        
        
        });
            });
        });`

Comment: do you see a typo? Blank stills.

Comment: I guess im gonna have to pass the whole form through jquery... Guess mixing the two does not work.

Comment: Without seeing your query.php I can't tell, do you have the return content type in the `header()` as `Javascript/json` ??

Comment: Yes. I will get to the bottom of this man. Unless you want to see the whole query.php? Thanks anyway.

Comment: We can take this to chat if you like? Where I can help better. [Join it here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136100/discussion-between-kyle-and-rge90).

Comment: Thats nice but I fixed the problem with a query instead. Had to do magic. Good day man!